# Custom Taxonomy in custom REST API search

Tags: wp-query, custom-taxonomy, search, rest-api, json

I am building my first theme where I use a custom search and I would like to include the ability to search by custom taxonomy.

Currently, the taxonomy term shows up in Postman but no posts with that taxonomy appear in the search results.

```
"albums": [
        {
            "albumTitle": "Aerobic Dance",
            "albumImage": "<img src=\"https://vebajefo.local/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/BLOOM001_AerobicDance_Cover-400x400.jpg\" />",
            "catalog_id": "BLOOM001 Aerobic Dance",
            "permalink": "https://vebajefo.local/albums/bloom001-aerobic-dance/",
            "postType": "albums",
            "albumGenres": {
                "genres": "Genres: <a href=\"https://vebajefo.local/genre/80s-pop/\">80s Pop</a>."
            }
        }
    ],
```

My current setup has a CPT called “albums” and a custom taxonomy called “genres”. This taxonomy is assigned only to “albums”. Every album is assigned with the lowest taxonomy term in the hierarchy. For example: If my genres are Jazz > Bebop > Big Band, the album is checked with only “Big Band”. In my case: Pop > 80s

In functions.php, I registered a custom Rest API search:

```
require get_theme_file_path('/inc/search-route.php');



function aftersunsetmusic_custom_rest () {
    register_rest_field( 'post', 'authorName', 'albumGenres', array(
        'get_callback' => function() {return get_the_author() ;}
    ) );
}

add_action('rest_api_init', 'aftersunsetmusic_custom_rest');
```

In the search-route.php, I defined the search query like this:

```
<?php

add_action('rest_api_init', 'aftersunsetmusicRegisterSearch');

function aftersunsetmusicRegisterSearch() {
    register_rest_route( 'aftersunsetmusic/v1', 'search', array(
        'methods' => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
        'callback' => 'aftersunsetmusicSearchResults',
        'permission_callback' => '__return_true',
    ) );
}

function aftersunsetmusicSearchResults ($data) {
    $mainQuery = new WP_Query(array(
        'post_type' => array('post', 'page', 'albums', 'artists'),
        's' => sanitize_text_field($data['term'])
    ));

    $results = array(
        'blog' => array(),
        'albums' => array(),
        'artists' => array(),
    );

    while($mainQuery->have_posts()) {
        $mainQuery->the_post();


        if (get_post_type() == 'post') {

            $description = null;
            if(has_excerpt()) {
                $description = get_the_excerpt();
            } else {
                $description = wp_trim_words( get_the_content(),18);
            }

            array_push($results ['blog'], array(
                'title' => get_the_title(),
                'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                'blogImage' => get_the_post_thumbnail(), 
                'authorName' => get_the_author(),
                'description' => $description,
            ));
        }

        if (get_post_type() == 'albums') {
            $relatedArtists = get_field('album_artists');

            if ($relatedArtists) {
                foreach($relatedArtists as $artist) {
                    array_push($results['artists'], array(
                        'artistName' => get_the_title($artist),
                        'permalink' => get_the_permalink($artist),
                        'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url( $artist, '' ),
                        'postType' => get_post_type($artist),
                    ));
                }
            }
            

            $albumtitle = get_field('album_title');

            array_push($results ['albums'], array(
                'albumTitle' => $albumtitle,
                'albumImage' => get_the_post_thumbnail(0,'medium'),
                'catalog_id' => get_the_title(),
                'permalink' => get_the_permalink(), 
                'postType' => get_post_type(),
                'albumGenres' => get_the_taxonomies( ),
            ));
        }
        

        if (get_post_type() == 'artists') {

            array_push($results['artists'], array(
                'artistName' => get_the_title(),
                'permalink' => get_the_permalink(),
                'image' => get_the_post_thumbnail_url( ),
                'postType' => get_post_type(),
            ));
        }
    }




    $results ['artists'] = array_values(
        array_unique($results['artists'], SORT_REGULAR));

    return $results;


}
```

I would like to add the ability to search the albums by its exact taxonomy term and its parent taxonomy.
For example: If an album is assigned to “Big Band” and the taxonomy hierarchy is Jazz > Bebop > Big Band, this album shall appear when searching for “Jazz”, or “Bebop”, or “Big Band”.

How do I achieve that?

I have tried to modify the search query by using the `pre_get_posts filter` but I am not quite sure how and where to include them.

Comment: "*to add the ability to search the albums by its exact taxonomy term and its parent taxonomy*" - you mean, as part of `$mainQuery` (which searches in 4 post types)? So for example, when searching for "Big Band", you want to search posts which contains that keyword in the post title/content, *or* that the posts are assigned to the `genres` taxonomy term named "Big Band"?

Comment: @SallyCJ The latter, and only for the posts from the cpt "albums". In the case of "Big Band", I would like to search posts from the cpt "albums" that are assigned to the **genres** taxonomy "Big Band", as well as any hierarchical parent of "Big Band", namely "Jazz" and/or "Bebop".

Comment: At the end, there shall be two ways to search for cpt "albums" Either by title, or custom taxonomy **genres**. I have excluded the post content from search results by replacing the post content with an acf wysiwyg field)

Comment: What I was asking is, whether you want the search results be part of the `$mainQuery->have_posts()` loop in your `aftersunsetmusicSearchResults` function, or that the search can be independent (e.g. using different function or maybe even a separate REST API route like `aftersunsetmusic/v1/search-albums`)?

Comment: I want the search results be part of the `$mainQuery->have_posts()`.  But I haven't really thought about the other options. What would be the benefits of having the search independent using a different function, or REST API route?

Comment: I was just confused because right now your query is already searching posts in the `albums` CPT, except that the search is by the title/excerpt/content of the post, i.e. if the keyword is `foo`, then your query will search for posts containing `foo` in the post title/excerpt/content. That's what the `s` argument does by default. Then you commented, "*only for the posts from the cpt "albums"*" and "*there shall be two ways to search for cpt "albums" Either by title, or custom taxonomy **genres***". Hence I became even more wanting to know about that "independent" thing.